# PayPal adaptive payment delayed chained payment's receiver configurations

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal adaptive payment delayed chained payment. The process is unintuitive.

**Q1: How to process the payment to the secondary receiver?**

API calls are made as below:
1. Make Pay API call with actionType=PAY_PRIMARY which will only process the payment to the primary receiver
2. Explicitly process the payment to secondary receiver.

How do I process step 2 above? Do I use ExecutePayment API operation? (This does not look correct since in the documentation it says to use payKey however payKey would be expired by the time I need to process the payment to the secondary receiver.)

**Q2: Is it ok to use SECONDARYONLY as feesPayer in delayed chained payment?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A1:** You would make a call to **ExecutePayment** passing the PayKey as a parameter. To clear up your doubts, the PayKey has a shelf life of 3 hours **before** the payment is initiated.

Once the payment has been approved by the customer (i.e. the first leg of the chained payment is completed) the PayKey becomes permanent and does not expire.

For a delayed chained payment, PayPal gives you 90 days to explicitly complete the second leg. After that, it will not allow you to do so, and the primary would need to manually send the money to the secondary receiver.

**A2:** Yes, but you can only use this variable when you have a single secondary receiver.

Comment: When registering for the application id (required for the API) when selecting the chained payment, under the feePayer selection it clearly state that "secondary" is only for the instant chained payment.

Comment: My first question is how do you process the payment to the secondary in delayed chained payment? Is there an API call I can use or login to paypal and explicitly do it?

Comment: Sandbox testing says otherwise. Try it out yourself.
I've edited to clarify the first answer (You already had the correct method listed in your question, I thought you only needed clarification on the lifespan of the paykey)

Comment: @Lenny Do you have any example for your A1 (answer 1). I am new to paypal and I am not getting how to execute the delayed payment. It will be great for me to have an example.

Comment: @lakumg: I suggest that you first do a regular chained payment to make sure you have that basic step of paying two people working correctly. Once you've done that, then change the actionType to PAY_PRIMARY.   When you redirect the buyer to paypal and they approve the purchase, only the first leg will be complete (i.e. primary receiver gets 100% of money).  The next step is to make a call to ExecutePayment, using THE SAME paykey from step 1.  This will initiate the second leg of the transaction from primary to secondary.  You have up to 90 days to complete this second step